# How to change the image on UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view with multiple images. The images are scrollable.

I am using the following code:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

scrollView.delegate = self;

scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;


NSInteger numberOfViews = [arrayImage count];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++)
{
    CGFloat yOrigin = i * scrollView.frame.size.width;
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin  +30, 0, self.view.frame.size.width-60 , self.view.frame.size.height)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrayImage objectAtIndex:i]];
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * numberOfViews,0);
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView release]
```

The application will work with iPad orientations, but the images are not properly scrolled in the landscape mode.

It works fine with portrait mode, but the images merge in landscape mode.

If somebody has any idea, please share....

Comment: i have a slider at the bottom which contains the images, i want to show the respective image on the screen as selected from the UISlider. The image will shown at the last UIImageView but i want to show it on the current UIImageView. please help..

Comment: check autoresize option of uiscrollview disabled it.

Comment: I have posted an answer...which is useful for sliding an image and show image in imageview...

Comment: Have you reloaded/Recreated this scroll view on screen orientation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the image frame for that purpose everytime the interface orientation changes or you have to redraw the images again after the change in orientation

Comment: Accept the answer if it has solved your problem, so that it can help others in solving same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...

```
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

int scrollWidth = 120;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,80);     


int xOffset = 0;
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:0]];

for(int index=0; index < [imagesName count]; index++)
{       
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    img.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
    img.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 0, 50, 50);
    NSLog(@"image: %@",[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]);
    img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:index]];
    [images insertObject:img atIndex:index];         
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,110); 
    [scrollView addSubview:[images objectAtIndex:index]];

    xOffset += 70;
}
```

Set this...

```
imagesName = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"image1.jpg",@"image2.jpg",@"image3.jpg",@"image4.jpg",@"image5.jpg",@"image6.png",@"image7.png",@"image9.png",nil];
images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: I think u want to slide images that are in scrollview and display which is selected right??

Comment: Then I think this answer must be useful to u...because I have implemented the same...:)